# How do I get the build number from where I executed a rebuild?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

When I click "rebuild" from the page of a build jenkins rebuilds and runs a new job- a new job with a new jenkins build number.

How do I get the build number of the job where I executed the rebuild?

Im not talking about the previous build number.

Say Im on build 10. I go to build 5 and click rebuild. How do I *that* build number (5) from inside the pipeline like I can with `env.BUILD_NUMBER`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I assume that you are using Groovy Pipeline and already know the Global Variable (see Global Variable Reference).

1. The `currentBuild` variable has a field `rawBuild` that return a [hudson.model.Run](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html) object
2. Call `rawBuildObject#getCauses()` or `rawBuildObject#getCauses()` and return some Cause object.

script below:

```
node {
    stage('test advance script') {
            echo "current build number: ${currentBuild.number}"
            echo "previous build number: ${currentBuild.previousBuild.getNumber()}"
            def causes = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses()
            echo "causes: ${causes}"
            def rebuildCause0 = currentBuild.rawBuild.getCause(com.sonyericsson.rebuild.RebuildCause)
            echo "rebuildCause0: ${rebuildCause0}"
            echo "rebuild up number: ${rebuildCause0.getUpstreamBuild()}"
        }
}
```

But as we discuss in chat, the Rebuilder Plugin use `CauseAction` in a wrong way. If it is fixed as [this](https://github.com/tianzhipeng-git/rebuild-plugin/commit/370239a610a90c369d50759eb9c264830ea72e0b), console output should be:

```
current build number: 72
previous build number: 71
causes: [hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause@679c1066, job/DMP/job/test-pipeline/63[hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause@679c1066]]
rebuildCause0: job/DMP/job/test-pipeline/63[hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause@679c1066]
rebuild up number: 63
```

> Remember to `scriptApproval` when you see errors like this:
>
> `Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.Run
>   getCauses. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this
>   signature.`

Comment: This does not appear to work. Echoing "${causes}" just shows `[hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause@ad8c8004]`. And trying to call getOriginalNumber throws `Cannot invoke method getOriginalNumber() on null object`

Comment: This is a "rebuild" not a "replay". could this be what I want https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/project-inheritance/hudson/plugins/project_inheritance/projects/rebuild/RebuildCause.html. How do i use that?

Comment: Sorry but I dont know what do you mean by 'rebuild'.  My answer works when I click'replay' on a job's build history.

Comment: Do you use this plugin?: https://github.com/jenkinsci/rebuild-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sonyericsson/rebuild/RebuildCause.java

Comment: I read the ReBuilder plugin's source code that I mentioned above. I found that this plugin use CauseAction WRONG.

Comment: I don't get how/why it's extending the UserIdCause

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178615/discussion-between--and-red888).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can curl your own jenkins builds:

```
def getOriginalRebuildNum(String jobUrl = "${JOB_URL}"){
    def urlJsonPath
    def buildNumber
    def result
    ansiColor('xterm') {
        try {
            buildNumber = "${BUILD_NUMBER}"
            urlJsonPath = "${JOB_URL}/${buildNumber}/api/json"
            while (!buildNumber.isEmpty()) {
                result = buildNumber
                buildNumber = sh(
                        script:
                                """
                            curl -s $urlJsonPath \
                                | jq -r '.actions[] 
                                | select(."_class" == "hudson.model.CauseAction") .causes[] 
                                | select(.upstreamBuild != null).upstreamBuild'
                                """,
                        returnStdout: true).trim()
                urlJsonPath = "${JOB_URL}/${buildNumber}/api/json"
            }
            echo "Original Build: ${JOB_URL}/${result}/"
        }
        catch (err) {
            "Error: Could not retrieve original Build Number from ${urlJsonPath} - $err"
            result = "${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        }
    }
    return result
}
```