# How do I get the "parentNumber" in my Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am using the Artifactory plugin.

When I rebuild a Jenkins job and deploy to jfrog,  I see this in the build info json:

[image]

This is super useful to me and I can't find how to get that in the Jenkins pipeline anywhere- its the job from which it was rebuilt.

How do I get that in my pipeline? I look in the build info object but it's not there:

```
def artifactory = Artifactory.server 'myserver.jfrog.io'
def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
echo buildInfo.dump()
```

Comment: Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974682/how-do-i-get-the-build-number-from-where-i-executed-a-rebuild

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the build number from where I executed a rebuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974682/how-do-i-get-the-build-number-from-where-i-executed-a-rebuild)